# SVG textPath on circle looks like spiral on Edge?

Tags: javascript, svg, microsoft-edge

I am trying to have have some text fit around a circle path. This works as expected in Firefox and Chrome, but Edge turns the text in a spiral when I add the `textLength` attribute (Which is needed to make it fit the full circle).

Is there some way to fix this, or a different method of making the text fully justified?

(The spiral effect in Edge is more pronounced depending on the text - from a little out, to wildly off the circle)

```html
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="220" height="220">
        <circle fill="#eeeeee" cx="110" cy="110" r="110"/>
        <path id="textpath" stroke-width="1" stroke="#000" fill="transparent" d="M170 110c0 33.137-26.863 60-60 60s-60-26.863-60-60 26.863-60 60-60 60 26.863 60 60z"/>
        <text dy="0" textLength="370" font-size="21px" fill="#444442">
          <textPath xlink:href="#textpath">Reviews * Reviews * Reviews * Reviews *</textPath>
        </text>
    </svg>
```

Comment: In this case you may need to recalculate the value of the font size based on the length of the path. Please take a look at this answer second update: [Animate marquee on SVG curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56041826/animate-marquee-on-svg-curve/56042973#56042973)

Comment: @enxaneta I have multiple with different text on each, and I need them to have the same font size.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the "dy" property and the "textLength" property, modify the code as below:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="220" height="220">
    <circle fill="#eeeeee" cx="110" cy="110" r="110" />
    <path id="textpath" stroke-width="1" stroke="#000" fill="transparent" d="M170 110c0 33.137-26.863 60-60 60s-60-26.863-60-60 26.863-60 60-60 60 26.863 60 60z" />
    <text dy="-5" textLength="372" font-size="21px" fill="#444442">
        <textPath xlink:href="#textpath">Reviews * Reviews * Reviews * Reviews *</textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```

The result in Edge browser as below:

[image]

Comment: I need it to be spaced evenly even if the text is changed. With this, any variation of the text makes it go wildly off the path.

Comment: If that is the case, I think you need to dynamically generate the SVG element. you could refer to [this article](http://bl.ocks.org/bycoffe/3404776) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45105203/how-to-rotate-text-around-its-centroid-vertically-flip-in-svg-d3).

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I could come up with was to use javascript to detect the browser then calculate `letter-spacing` to use instead of `textLength`.

This seems to fix the problem in Edge. IE is a little out due it not getting the width accurately.

```
if (/MSIE 9/i.test(navigator.userAgent) || /rv:11.0/i.test(navigator.userAgent) || /MSIE 10/i.test(navigator.userAgent) || /Edge\/\d./i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
  var textCircle = document.querySelectorAll('svg');
  for(i=0; i < textCircle.length; i++) {
    circleText(i);
  };
}
function circleText(i) {
  var str = textCircle[i].querySelector('textPath').textContent;
  var test = textCircle[i].querySelector('text').cloneNode(false);
  textCircle[i].appendChild(test);
  test.appendChild(document.createTextNode(str));
  test.removeAttribute('textLength');
  var w = test.getBBox().width;
  textCircle[i].removeChild(test);
  var dif = textCircle[i].querySelector('text').getAttribute('textLength') - w;
  textCircle[i].querySelector('text').style.letterSpacing = (dif / str.length) / 21 + 'em';
  textCircle[i].querySelector('text').removeAttribute('textLength');
};
```